# React Native: Can I include the bottom navigation bar in the screen that is not in Tab.Navigator

Tags: android, react-native, bottomnavigationview

Im a beginner with React Native.
I have a bottom navigation including 4 components [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bB9ZE.png) and
[a stack navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRf4F.png). In the Index, it includes [the bottom navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhwrJ.png).
In component HistoryScreen which is not inside the BottomTabNavigator, and I want it has the same bottom navigation like the first picture too.
How can I make it?
Thank you for reading

Updated: I already solved this just by using nested stack navigator: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can create custom TabBar component,
And you can use the navigate without navigation props from the docs [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/) and you'll got it

Comment: Thank you but it's not what I want.